# Adding view with weight programmatically to LinearLayout in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

***EDIT --- Adding the full code***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/barsContainer"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var barsIndex = BooleanArray(30) { false }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        val layoutParams =
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 80, 1f)
        viewBinding.barsContainer.weightSum = (barsIndex.size).toFloat()
        for (index in barsIndex.indices) {
            val barView = View(this)
//            layoutParams.setMargins(60, 60, 60, 60)
            barView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
            barView.layoutParams = layoutParams
            viewBinding.barsContainer.addView(barView)
        }
    }
}
```

Well I've searched a lot and found a lot of answers regarding this question but still it has not worked for me so far.

I wanna add a number of bars with equal width to a LinearLayout.
this is what I got so far:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/barsContainer"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

and In my Activity.kt:

```
viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(viewBinding.root)

val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 80, 1f)
for (index in barsIndex.indices) {
     val barView = View(this)
     barView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
     barView.layoutParams = layoutParams
     viewBinding.barsContainer.addView(barView, index)
     }

viewBinding.barsContainer.requestLayout()
```

still it doesn't respect the weight (third parameter) and if I add some width it works but that's not what I want.

I tried both 0 and `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` for the width it still does not work.

adding Margin to children doesn't work either!

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i just edit some of your code to just edit color and height
you just need add this line befor  the loop

```
        barsContainer.weightSum = (barsIndex.size).toFloat()
```

To make sure that he takes the correct weights so that he divides the layout correctly as well

```
  val barsContainer = findViewById<LinearLayoutCompat>(R.id.barsContainer)
    val barsIndex = arrayListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4)
    barsContainer.weightSum = (barsIndex.size).toFloat()
    val layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(0, 150, 1f)
    for (index in barsIndex.indices) {
        val barView = View(this)
        barView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff${(index+1)*22}00"))
        barView.layoutParams = layoutParams
        barsContainer.addView(barView,index)
    }
```

[image]

```
  val barsIndex = arrayListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4)
    barsContainer.weightSum = (barsIndex.size).toFloat()
    val layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(0, 150, 1f)
    layoutParams.marginEnd=1
    layoutParams.marginStart=1
    for (index in barsIndex.indices) {
        val barView = View(this)
        barView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff${(index+1)*22}00"))
        barView.layoutParams = layoutParams
        barsContainer.addView(barView,index)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The result is pretty much what I want, but I used your code, even changed viewbinding to classic finding views still it doesn't show! maybe I'm doing something wrong!? while you are at it can you add like 1dp margin between the views?

Comment: i just edit it @ArmanMomeni

Comment: Thanks dude, I still can't get my head around why it isn't working my side

Comment: post the full code and full xml code plase

Comment: Added the full code.

Comment: you want add 30 item ?

Comment: Yeah, does it matter tho? I'm trying to do it this way so it can be changed any time

Comment: i just run your code and it works for me

Comment: i add some anime when fill the view